# NMOS/PMOS Saturation

Tags: transistors, nmos, saturation, pmos

If I recall correctly, saturation occurs if \$V_{GS}>V_{TH}\$ and \$V_{DS}>V_{Dsat}\$ for NMOS. But is there an upper limit for the voltage? Like, when does a transistor not saturate after continually increasing \$V_{GS}\$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NMOS, the conditions \$V_{GS}>V_{TH}\$ and \$V_{DS}>V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$ ensure saturation.

So an NMOS in saturation can come out of saturation if the applied \$V_{GS}\$ is increased beyond \$V_{GS}=V_{DS}+V_{TH}\$.

Comment: The *other* limit is the gate oxide breakdown voltage, where everything goes up in smoke …